# is thare any offline support relational database that syncs like pouch-couch

Tags: mysql, nosql, couchdb, relational-database, pouchdb

I want to develop an angular  application using electron  which works offline .
so i need database to sync with server . as my application is based on relational database i cannot choose pouchDB -couchDB 
is there any solution for structured database that syncs like pouchDB

Answer (score 2):

Not every system is pure NoSQL, In may case all of them are a mix between different kinds of technologies. Your system will be more flexible and scalable if you choose a NoSQL DB like CouchDB/PouchDB for replication.

There are other products that tries to solve the replication in a relational model. But I didn't find any product that allow to sync with and embedded JS relational DB like PouchDB.

Yo can check SymmetricDS (https://www.symmetricds.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.As my database is very much structured i cannot go for NoSQL . Symmetricds is not feasible for my application because it will replicate entire server db to client.. i heard of something relational pouch do you have any idea